# write access to Keywords?

Tags: 2009

"To add a Keyword (to a Category or Keyword), you must have Category Management rights and Write permissions for the Category"

That is the statement from SDL.

I have users who are "regional" and "country" editor + webmaster. On each category we have  Author|Editor|Webmaster = WRITE permissions.

On country publication in web site managment:

- Country Webmaster has "Category Managment" rights set
- Webmaster has "Category Managment" rights set

Country Webmaster is a member of Webmaster.
Result: On the country website; user can add keywords.

On regionX publication in content management:

- RegionX Webmaster has "Category Managment" rights set
- Webmaster has "Category Managment" rights set

RegionX Webmaster is a member of Region Webmaster.
Region Webmaster is a member of Webmaster

Result: On the RegionX website; user can NOT add keywords.

The only difference I see is that there is one extra "layer" of membership scope on the regional membership scope.

But I fail to see why user cannot add keywords on a regional layer - is not access the sum of all settings (members of + scope)? Must I add give "Region Webmaster" write access to each category?

Comment: Yes, access is a sum or union across membership "chains." But it is an *intersection* for scope up a given user/group membership chain. For the RegionX > Region Webmaster > Webmaster memberships, are there any scope restrictions? Also, are any of the Categories localized or any exclusions? The only other thing I can think of is if the user doesn't belong to RegionX Webmaster or one of the groups is missing any rights for the publication (might need at least one).

Answer (score 5):

As per my understanding, I have drawn a flow chart of yours access rights setup

[image: Category Management Access Rights Setup]

Re-verify below steps:-

1. Add `Webmaster` group on all publications with `Category Management` Access
2. Add `Webmaster` group on Root category / specific categories with <kbd>READ</kbd> + <kbd>WRITE</kbd> access
3. On `Country Webmaster` group,

   - Insert `Webmaster` group
   - Select only Country related publication checkbox's
4. On `Region Webmaster` group,

   - Insert `Webmaster` group
   - Select only Region related publication checkbox's
5. On `RegionX Webmaster` group,

   - Insert `Region Webmaster` group
   - Select only specific Region publication checkbox's, which are applicable under RegionX
6. Finally insert

   - `Country Webmaster` group on country users and select only applicable countries for this user
   - `RegionX Webmaster` group on region users and select only applicable regions for this user

Now it should work and hope this will help you.

***Note:*** I don't see major usage of RegionX webmaster. You can remove this group and use only Region webmaster